# Include MergeCom DICOM toolkit with ios using Swift

Tags: c++, ios, c, swift, dicom

I am very new to adding c/c++ library to iOS project. My requirement is to add DICOM toolkit (written in c/c++) to my swift ios project. I have spent two days with googling to find steps how to include and use it, but i could not find any such blogs that are using DICOM toolkit by Mergecom.

Can somebody help here..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing (apparent) special about the merge toolkit. Look at any tutorial about using C code/libraries.

Here is one;

https://maniacdev.com/2015/02/tutorial-a-quick-guide-to-using-c-libraries-within-swift-code

Have you asked Merge for a sample app?

Comment: Thanks John for your reply. There is no support for iOS from Merge. They said use the c++ libraries. 
So i found another toolkit thats providing support for iOS with Objective C for DICOM related stuff called Leadtools.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this.  If you are working from the publicly available sources, you'll need to:

1 - make the DCMTK sources build their libraries for iOS using Xcode
2 - make a Objective-C bridging library, like iiDicom work on iOS
3 - create additional Objective-C bridging code to access DCMTK via Swift

To get DCMTK + iiDicom working under iOS, it will take about a month of off-and-on work to get both libraries ready for initial use with Xcode.